# Alembic autogenerate recerates existing indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am using a simple mixin for all my tables:

```
class IdMixIn:
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
```

Example table:

```
class MyTable(Base, IdMixIn):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    my_col: str = sa.Column(sa.String)
```

I have about thirty of these tables, and if I run `alembic revision --autogenerate` I will then have thirty rows, one for each table of an index creation:

```
op.create_index(op.f('ix_my_table_id'), 'my_table', ['id'], unique=False)
```

However, in postgres, each of these already have an index, named something like `my_table_pkey`. How do I let alembic know these already exist for all the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is  no need to create index on primary key column, so you can only write

```py
class IdMixIn:
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Postgresql will automatically create index for this column

Comment: So this answer doesn't actually solve the base question of "how do I tell alembic about existing indexing", but does help in particular here as it's what I need so thank you! If you happen to know also how to set a mixin to different index names on different tables, would be good to know.